# No Negative Prefix

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

```
def minOperation(A,N):
    operations = 0
    for i in range(N):
        if sum(A[:i+1])<0:
            A[i] = A[i]+1
            operations += 1
    return operations
```

What am I doing wrong in this code?

The question says:

> Given an array A[] of N integers. In each operation, the person can increase the ith element by 1 (i.e. set A[i] = A[i] + 1). The task is to calculate the minimum number of operations required such that there is no prefix in the array A[] whose sum is less than zero. (i.e. for all i, This condition should be satisfied A[1] + A[2] + .. + A[i] >= 0).

Comment: What is the issue with the code? This seems like a Dynamic Programming problem.

Comment: Can you add a link to the original problem? It will help in understanding the problem better.

Comment: there is no existing link for the problem, it is from a contest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what I am doing wrong in this code

Your code assumes that a sum that becomes negative, can always be solved by just adding one to the last term, but you might need to suddenly add a one to all terms visited so far. For example:

```
A = [1, 1, 1, 1, -9]
```

Your code will not add a one to the first 4 terms, and then will only change -9 to -8, but that doesn't do enough. At that moment you really should consider that *all* previous terms should get an extra point, so that the prefix sum becomes 2+2+2+2-8, which then is still OK.

So the idea is to keep track of how many ones you have added, which will at the same time indicate at which index you can add the next one -- if needed. Each time your running total becomes negative, you know how many operations you would need in addition. If those are available, then use them to get the total to zero.

Code:

```
def minOperations(lst):
    operations = 0
    total = 0
    for i, val in enumerate(lst):
        total += val
        if total < 0:
            # Add the number of operations to make the total 0
            operations += -total
            total = 0
            # If more operations are needed than available...
            if operations > i + 1:
                return -1  # ...it cannot be solved
    return operations

# Example run
lst = [1, 1, -5, 3, 2, -4, -1]
print(minOperations(lst))  # 3
```

NB: it is not efficient to recalculate the sum of the subarray at each iteration. Just keep adding the current value to a running sum.

Answer (score 0):

Walk through array and calculate prefix sums.

If for every sum inequality

```
- PrefixSum[i] <= i
```

is true, then result is

```
max(0, - min(PrefixSum))
```

else result is `None` (we cannot add enough ones)